Execution timeout error in ASP.NET Core Web API with EF Core
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project using EF Core for database related operations. The database is hosted in Azure and I am using SQL Server authentication to get access to my database and for execution of my SQL queries.
I sometimes get this error  when one API method at url GET:api/GetCommonPageUser is run:

Execution Timeout Expired.The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

This is stack trace
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()     
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__281_0(Object obj)     
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---     
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---     
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()     
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    
at Project.Repository.Repositories.AccountRepository.GetAccountUserDetailsById(Int32 user_id, Int32 account_id, String identity_id) in D:\a\1\s\Project.Repository\Repositories\AccountRepository.cs:line 2123     
at Project.Api.Controllers.AccountController.GetAccountUserDetailsById(Int32 user_id, Int32 account_id) in D:\a\1\s\Project.Api\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 685     

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)     
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)     
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)     
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)     
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)     
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)     
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|26_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

From the error, I was able to identify that there is something wrong with my method named GetAccountUserDetailsById and this method is executing query on a table CommonPageUser and this table has 2'509'978 rows.
This is the Linq query :
await context.CommonPageUsers
             .Where(x => x.email == accountUserDetails.email 
                         && x.account_id == account_id 
                         && x.is_user_created && !x.is_deleted)
             .OrderByDescending(o => o.last_updated_datetime_local)
             .Select(s => new 
                          { 
                              s.move_in_date, s.move_out_date, 
                              s.lease_start_date, s.lease_end_date 
                          })
             .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync();

So is that issue due to the large amount of data?
I have noticed that sometime my endpoint give success response with proper data but sometime give me that error also.
Also I have noticed that when I tried to execute the query like below
SELECT * 
FROM CommonPageUsers 
WHERE email = 'john.doe@xyz.com' AND account_id = 381;

It was taking around 3 minutes in SQL Server Management Studio, but after sometime, it was taking around 0 seconds.
Has anyone faced this kind of issue? If so, your suggestions and solutions are welcomed.
Thank you for help.
My expectation to identify that what is the issue. Is it my backend code, or does SQL Server have too many open connections?

"So is that issue due to large number of data ??" Yes and no. It is issue that probably you do not have index on email column or better index on account_id + email.

By default, SSMS waits forever for a query to complete. If you get this error, this is because you have set a query timeout under Tools->Options->Query Execution->SQL Server->General->Execution time-out. Set the time-out to 0 to wait forever.
